# JMS Message Counter

Tags: java, jms

I would like to display JMS queue statistics on the page where I may present how many messages are in the queues

Is there any way to do that in universal way (without using any provider specific API) whithout iterating through all messages?

I know that I may achive that using QueueBrowser.getEnumeration() however it is too costly to iterate over all messages just for simple counting functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reference to statistics in the [JMS 1.1 spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/docs-136352.html).

My experience w/ statistics is that they're available through vendor-specific interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that it is possible in the manner you seek.

Although your question specifically asks about non-provider specific methods I will offer this:

[ActiveMQ can be monitored via JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) which allows you to interrogate many things including queue size. You can always create an interface which you can then extend on a per-provider basis (and as an example you would retrieve queue size from an ActiveMQ provider implementation via JMX).

Answer (score 0):

[QueueBrowser](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jms/javadoc-102a/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) is the only *standard* way of browsing messages in a Queue without consuming them.

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is specific to WebLogic, and it uses JMSDestinationRuntimeMBean, but every Application Server should allow you to do something equivalent:

http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/01/counting-jms-messages-present-in-jms.html